# Borders on some sides

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I am coding a client for a tic-tac-toe variant. The game logic changes are not relevant to this question

I am trying to show a 'hash-tag' tic-tac-toe grid like the one below.

[image: grid example]

I initially thought of using borders on the buttons, or the frames containing the buttons, but other questions found difficulty (and a couple of complicated workarounds) when adding borders to specific sides.

I would rather not resort to a `Canvas` object for drawing the game, since this feels - as do the others mentioned - like a cheap workaround at the expense of readability.

How can I add these lines in between frames/grid columns/labels/buttons?

Comment: First code? Don't understand where ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by putting white frames inside a black one and using the `padx` and `pady` arguments of `grid`:

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frames = []
for i in range(3):
    frames.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        frames[i].append(tk.Frame(frame, bg='white', width=50, height=50))
        frames[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, 
                          padx=((j != 0) * 2,  (j != 2) * 2),
                          pady=((i != 0) * 2,  (i != 2) * 2))

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`padx` and `pady` can either take a single number to get a symmetrical result or a tuple of values:`padx=(<left>, <right>)` and `pady=(<top>, <bottom>)`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
# I use python 2
import Tkinter as tk 
# For Python 3 use import tkinter as tk 

def create_grid(event=None):
    w = c.winfo_width() # Get current width of canvas
    h = c.winfo_height() # Get current height of canvas
    c.delete('grid_line') # Will only remove the grid_line

    # Creates all vertical lines at intevals of 100 except for first and last
    for i in range(100, w - 100, 100):
        c.create_line([(i, 0), (i, h)], tag='grid_line')

    # Creates all horizontal lines at intevals of 100 except for first and last
    for i in range(100, h - 100, 100):
        c.create_line([(0, i), (w, i)], tag='grid_line')

root = tk.Tk()

c = tk.Canvas(root, height=300, width=300, bg='white')
c.pack(fill=tk.NONE, expand=True)

c.bind('<Configure>', create_grid)

root.mainloop()
```

I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011751/3512538) answer and tweaked it a bit so the edges won't be shown

Comment: In the question, I said *I would rather not use a `Canvas` object for drawing the game*

Comment: @speedstyle When someone answers the question you'vee asked, they're not necessarily answering only your question but the questions future researchers may ask. I think this answer may be useful to future visitors searching on how to have gridlike layout.

Comment: True; apologies.